# I need a TreeMap in which Key will be id and value (will be a hasMap in that name will be id & values will be rest details) for every id data?

Tags: java

```
TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myData = new TreeMap<>();

    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>(); //data present in this map will be name as key & Values will rest other details
    HashMap<String, String> lock = new HashMap<>(); //data present in this map Will be id as Key & Values will be name+Email

Iterator itr = lock.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator trans = data.entrySet().iterator();
        HashMap<String, String> vessel = new HashMap<>(); //Temp Holding of EachKey & value of name as key and rest as values
        TreeMap demo=new TreeMap();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry e = (Entry) itr.next();
            String key = (String) e.getKey();
            name = ReadExcel.getString((String) e.getValue(), 0);
            String email = ReadExcel.getString((String) e.getValue(), 1);
            while (trans.hasNext()) {
                vessel.clear();
                Entry ex = (Entry) trans.next();
                String NameVs = (String) ex.getKey();
                String emailVs = ReadExcel.getString((String) ex.getValue(), 0);
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NameVs) && email.equalsIgnoreCase(emailVs)) {
                    vessel.put(NameVs, data.get(NameVs));
                    //System.err.println(vessel.values());
                    myData.put(key, vessel);    //Putting data in treeMap 
                    System.out.println(myData.entrySet());
                    break;
                }
            }
            trans = data.entrySet().iterator();
        }
```

Need output as

> [1={RAM=aa@gmail.com Domulur 7894561230 }, 2={ANIL=xyZ@gmail.com MUM 8464648848 }] . If i have some data as "ID Name Email Address Mob". But the problem is if i use clear() data is replaced by last row data .For, Ex: [1={ANIL=xyZ@gmail.com MUM 8464648848 }, 2={ANIL=xyZ@gmail.com MUM 8464648848 }] and if i don't use clear(), values are appending. For ex,  [1={RAM=aa@gmail.com Domulur 7894561230,ANIL=xyZ@gmail.com MUM 8464648848  }, 2={RAM=aa@gmail.com Domulur 7894561230,ANIL=xyZ@gmail.com MUM 8464648848 }].

Need Help Thanks.

Comment: The first row of the code is :
TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myData = new TreeMap<>();

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question. Also if you wish to provide additional information, DO NOT add a comment, just edit your question!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same `HashMap<String, String>` instance as value for all the keys of your `TreeMap`, so of course all the keys will have the same value.

You should create a new `HashMap` for each key:

```
    ....
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Entry e = (Entry) itr.next();
        String key = (String) e.getKey();
        name = ReadExcel.getString((String) e.getValue(), 0);
        String email = ReadExcel.getString((String) e.getValue(), 1);
        while (trans.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> vessel = new HashMap<>();
            Entry ex = (Entry) trans.next();
            String NameVs = (String) ex.getKey();
            String emailVs = ReadExcel.getString((String) ex.getValue(), 0);
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NameVs) && email.equalsIgnoreCase(emailVs)) {
                vessel.put(NameVs, data.get(NameVs));
                myData.put(key, vessel);    //Putting data in treeMap 
                break;
            }
        }
        trans = data.entrySet().iterator();
    }  
    ....
```